# New method to disable wpautop after WP 4.3?

Tags: wp-autop

After WordPress 4.3, the old method of disabling wpautop no longer works. Has anyone discovered a new method for removing this function?

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop', 99 );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop', 99 );
```

Comment: This is f* nightmare, wpautop is done in Javascript now and nobody seems to now how to disable it. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/changes-in-wpautop-in-43-or-how-to-render-my-blog-unusable

Comment: @Eric Holmes is correct that the method mentioned in the question will *never* work as `remove_filter` must specify the same priority when the hook was registered with `add_filter`, which in this case is `10`, not `99`

Comment: @shea this is correct and anything else didn't worked to me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you don't use it at all, so why don't you just remove the filter?

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
```

I've tested it a few minutes ago (on WP 4.3) and it works.

p.s. I just saw that you use the same function. Sorry for that. What version are you using? This disables the wpautop on 4.3.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The reason that the code in the question doesn't work, is that when removing a filter or action, you also have to specify the same priority. When `wpautop` is added, it's priority is not specified, which defaults to 10.

Comment: I think it'd be more accurate to say that your comment is the correct answer, as it gives the explicit reason...

Answer (score 6):

On the javascript side, as a crude measure you could just replace the `wp.editor.autop` and `wp.editor.removep` with no ops:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', function () {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        if (typeof wp === 'object' && typeof wp.editor === 'object') {
            wp.editor.autop = function (text) { return text; };
            wp.editor.removep = function (text) { return text; };
        }
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}, 100 );
```

However on very limited testing although it seems to keep markup it does put it all on one line in the Text editor, which is pretty ugly...

Answer (score 1):

This works well. It's about the priority of the hook :

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'njengah_remove_autop', 0 );

function njengah_remove_autop($content) {

        // remove autop 

         remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );


        return $content;
}
```